# Close all elements of a menu (including submenus)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to create a multilevel menu based on the jquery click event. I got the second level elements open and closed, when you open one the other one closes.
    But I would like that the third level also closed when opening any second level element.

Also, could an item be opened by clicking on the body of the document?

and, what can I do so that the menu when it is open does not push the boxes down?

I attach the code fragment so please can you give me some ideas on how to solve it?, thanks

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4aL8xge0/2/

**this is my js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".open-submenu").click(function(){
  event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggleClass("show");
  });
});

var $items = $('.main-menu .item-menu > .open-submenu').click(function () {
 var submenu = $(this).next();
    $subs.not(submenu).hide()
    submenu.toggle();
});
var $subs = $items.next();
```

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-menu {
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.main-menu .item-menu {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.main-menu .item-menu .sub-menu, .main-menu .item-menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.main-menu .item-menu .show {
  display: block;  
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.border {
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.box-1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="item-menu">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">First level</a>
      <label class="open-submenu">▾</label>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a>Item 1.1</a></li>
        <li>
          <a>Second level</a>
          <label class="open-submenu">▾</label>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Third level</a></li>
            <li><a>Third level</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
  Item 1.3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-menu">
      <a>Item 2</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="item-menu">
      <a>Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-menu">
      <a>First level 4</a>
      <label class="open-submenu">▾</label>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a>Item 4.1</a>
          <label class="open-submenu">▾</label>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Item 4.1.1</a></li>
            <li>Item 4.1.2</li>
            <li>Item 4.1.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Item 4.2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="box-1">
    box 1
</section>

<section class="box-2">
    box 2
</section>
```